# 2 WAN routers share the same LAN network?

Tags: networking, router, lan, webserver, modem

I have 1 modem with 2 Public IPs assigned in bridge mode with 2 routers connected to it. Each router has a unique Public IP address. Router 1 has only servers connected to it, and router 2 is used for my wifi devices + desktops.

I have a unraid backup server connected to router 2 and want the servers on router 1 to be able to see it. How can I do this? The unraid backup server has a single ethernet port.

Router 1 is a TP-Link er605 and Router 2 is an Asus RT-AX86U

Comment: Hold on, _do_ you need two routers in the first place?

Comment: Essentially you can't, not properly... you might be able to setup static routes but the firewalls are going to be an issue. This is a situation where a home router(s) just don't make sense for this application, a single enterprise grade or SOHO router like OpenWRT with proper VLAN support could make this happen easily.

Comment: I use two public ips since the servers behind router 1 are heavy on traffic and I do not want to expose the public ip of these servers simply by browsing the internet on the same ip. Router 1 does support dual wan so maybe I could somehow forward one of the wans to router 2 so that router 2 has a different public ip but no dhcp? Router 1 has no wifi.

Comment: Honestly this shouldn't even need "dual WAN", much less dual routers... just one router with two public IP addresses. How are the addresses assigned – DHCP? PPP?

Comment: DHCP I believe from the modem

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good plan. Their public IP addresses are most likely served via DHCP, so behind router 1 you can't know what is the public IP address of router 2.

You should use only a single router. If you want two Wi-Fi networks, you can always use one of the boxes in bridged mode, so that it doesn't offer WAN connectivity at all and its DHCP server is turned off. However, with good operating systems like OpenWRT, you can set up an arbitrary number of network SSIDs even on a single router.

Rule of thumb is: if you want device X to connect to device Y reliably, they should be on the same network. Not behind different routers.

I kind of could understand the need for multiple public IP addresses if you want to run two web servers on port 80 for example, but since in your setup router 2 is not used for servers, it would be best to drop it completely. You don't need router 2's public IP address.

Comment: I use two public ips since the servers behind router 1 are heavy on traffic and I do not want to expose the public ip of these servers simply by browsing the internet on the same ip. Router 1 does support dual wan so maybe I could somehow forward one of the wans to router 2 so that router 2 has a different public ip but no dhcp? Router 1 has no wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that:

- You only have a small number of servers (i.e. it's not much work to manually configure the network settings on them.
- Router 1 is the one with the servers connected to it.
- Router 2 has an internal IP of 192.168.1.1 - I just need an IP for this explanation.

---

1. Disable the DHCP server on Router 1
2. Change the internal IP of Router 1 onto Router 2's subnet, i.e. its new IP is 192.168.1.2
3. Connect the two routers (LAN side) together - either directly or via a switch.
4. Use Static IP addresses on your servers (this will also need to be in the 192.168.1.x range)
5. Change the default gateway on your servers to 192.168.1.2

Since all your computers are now on the same network they should have no problem talking to each other.

Anything using DHCP will have its default GW set to 192.168.1.1 (Router 2) hence send traffic out over that router.

Your statically configured servers will all send traffic out over Router 1